# How to generate a vector 10000 times and each time store a certain position?

Tags: r, vector, repeat

So, I have a certain normal distribuition and its mean is replicated 10000 times in a vector. I need to find the 9th element in the vector that is out of the limits of control and store its position, which I've been able to do. Now, how to repeat this action 10000 times and store 10000 positions as integers?
This is what I have so far:

```
LCI = 1000 - 3*4^(1/2)

LCS = 1000 + 3*4/4^(1/2)

k = replicate(10000, (mean(rnorm(4, mean=1000, sd=4))))

k[k < LCI | k > LCS]

n = which(k %in% c(k[k < LCI | k > LCS]))

n[9]
```

Bonus question: then, what would be the best way of adding up all this 10000 numbers I got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I got the question totally - could you just loop over this and store it in a vector, summing the values afterwards?

```
#empty vector  
l <- c()

#making constant
LCI = 1000 - 3*4^(1/2)

LCS = 1000 + 3*4/4^(1/2)

#for loop with you code
for(i in 1:1000){


  k = replicate(10000, (mean(rnorm(4, mean=1000, sd=4))))

  #k[k < LCI | k > LCS] (don't need for the loop)

  n = which(k %in% c(k[k < LCI | k > LCS]))

  #store in empty vector as integer
  l[i] <- as.integer(n[9])
}

#check output
l

#sum of all values
sum(l)
```

Comment: I aprecciate your comment, Peter, it is actually what I was looking for. Thanks!